# when i start my app from shortcut it show me app not found?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an app, in which I am providing one facility to user, to add a shortcut to the home screen, and when user clicks shortcut, it opens the custom camera.

It's working fine on some devices, but on some devices it shows me this Toast: `App not found`  or `App isn't installed on your device` while my app is already installed.

So why I am getting this Toast if my app already installed?

Comment: All apps you install on your device provide shortcuts. If you mean default camera app by "custom camera", not all devices have the same app ID of the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so after doing some research I found that not all devices have the same app ID of the default camera application.

and I put `log` in android to print app id so when I run the app in Samsung and mi device then I get other app id and other device show me different app id for default camera application